# Date Time format too complex when bind the value, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a datepicker on my angularJS WCFrest project

[image]

i get the data using

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="txtOldDate" type="date" class="datepicker" ng-model="oldDate" />
</div>
```

but the data that acquired is too complex when i get the data

> Fri Dec 16 2016 00:00:00 GMT+07 (SE Asia Standard Time)

i just want to get the value like on the date picker interface

> 12/16/2016

this is my controller.js

```js
$scope.SearchApproval = function(employeeID, oldDate, newDate, departemen, approver) {
  var promiseGet = GetApproval.GetApprovalData($scope.employeeID, $scope.oldDate, $scope.newDate, $scope.departemen, $scope.approver);
  //GetApprovalData();
  promiseGet.then(function(pl) {
      $scope.GetApprovalData = pl.data
    },
    function(errorPl) {
      console.log('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
    });
}
```

is there any way to format the result?

i already try $filter

> $scope.oldDate = $filter('date')(new Date(dateString), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

but it give me this error

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2016-12-20` to be a date

Comment: why not save it as it is and filter it  to 'yyyy-MM-dd' only when you display it on the page?

Comment: because i want to send the data to uri and that format make request error because it is too long. something like `http://localhost:51458/ServiceRequest.svc/GetApproval?employeeID=22134&oldDate=Fri%20Dec%2009%202016%2000:00:00%20GMT+0700%20(SE%20Asia%20Standard%20Time)`

Comment: the right format should be `http://localhost:51458/ServiceRequest.svc/GetApproval?employeeID=&oldDate=2016-12-20)` @madalinivascu is there any way to convert the result before i send it to uri?

Comment: you can do a post request instead of get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answer to help me.

Finally i already solve my own problem. The problem is actually on input type = "date". when i change it to type = "text". it can work to send only the date.

this is the result

```
http://localhost:51458/ServiceRequest.svc/GetApproval?employeeID=&oldDate=2000-01-01
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [Angular Moment Js](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) and [Moment Js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) it might be helpful.

You can convert this as the below using moment js

```
$scope.oldDate = moment(dateString).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

To use this you have to add Angular moment in your project and which is explained in above link how to add using nuget or bower or npm.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var mydate = $scope.oldDate.getFullYear()+ "-" +  ($scope.oldDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + $scope.oldDate.getDate()
```